# Recursive list compressor gives strange results in Elm

Tags: list, elm

I have a dictionary which contains a series of keys with names "ls-1", "ls-2", "ls-3", etc. and a key "ls-count" stating how many there are. When one of these is deleted, say "ls-2" is deleted, I want to bubble the remainder up so that the old "ls-3" will become "ls-2" and so on.

(Yes, I know this is a really awkward way of storing a list, but it's because of the underlying data format. Please don't XY me.)

The code being used for this at the moment is:

```elm
updateDeleteField : String -> Model -> Model
updateDeleteField key model =
    let
        keyhyphenindex =
            String.indexes "-" key

        realKeyHyphenIndex =
            case (List.head keyhyphenindex) of
                Nothing ->
                    Debug.crash "Missing hyphen in expandable form deletion process"

                Just x ->
                    x

        keyPrehyphen =
            (String.slice 0 realKeyHyphenIndex key) ++ "-"

        countName =
            Debug.log "name of the count variable:" (keyPrehyphen ++ "count")

        removeResponse =
            Debug.log "remove the deleted item:" (killResponse model key)

        reduceCount =
            Debug.log "reduce the count:" (setResponse removeResponse countName (toString ((getResponseInt removeResponse countName 0) - 1)))

        -- Integrity bubble: check if we've reached the end of the list, if so we're done
        checkInteg value m =
            if value >= ((getResponseInt m countName 0)) then
                Debug.log "Completing.." m
            else
                let
                    -- Name of the current item
                    active =
                        Debug.log "active" (keyPrehyphen ++ (toString value))

                    -- Name of the next item
                    next =
                        Debug.log "next" (keyPrehyphen ++ (toString (value + 1)))

                in
                    case (Dict.get active m.character) of
                        -- If the current item is not missing, recurse onto the rest of the numbers
                        Just x ->
                            Debug.log ("Active is ok so moving on to " ++ (toString (value + 1))) (checkInteg (value + 1) m)

                        -- If the current item is missing, look at the next one
                        Nothing ->
                            case (Dict.get next m.character) of
                                -- If the next one is present, move it down to fill the current gap, then recurse
                                Just higher ->
                                    Debug.log ("Active is missing, bubbling" ++ next ++ " to " ++ active)
                                        (checkInteg (value) (setResponse (killResponse m next) active higher))

                                -- That being missing too should be impossible since only one thing can be deleted at a time
                                Nothing ->
                                    Debug.crash ("More than one form item deleted at once? " ++ active ++ " unset, so is " ++ next ++ ", deleted key is " ++ key)
    in
        checkInteg 1 reduceCount
```

The invoked functions and relevant parts of the data structures:

```elm
type alias Model =
    { character : Dict String String ... }

getResponse : Model -> String -> Maybe String
getResponse model key =
    Dict.get key model.character

setResponse : Model -> String -> String -> Model
setResponse model key value =
    let
        char = model.character
    in
        { model | character = Dict.insert key value char }

killResponse : Model -> String -> Model
killResponse model key =
    let
        char = model.character
    in
        { model | character = Dict.remove key char }

getResponseInt : Model -> String -> Int -> Int
getResponseInt model key default =
    case (Dict.get key model.character) of
        Nothing -> default
        Just x -> case (toInt x) of
            Err _ -> default
            Ok i -> i
```

Everything up to checkInteg works fine, but at that point the debug output goes crazy. It'll often print the Completed message before any of the others, or just stop after bubbling for no reason, or say it is bubbling but then not change anything. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell much given that so much depends on the undefined functions: getResponseInt, setResponse, etc, as well as Model. The `checkInteg` function is recursive and it's not at all clear to me that it is guaranteed to hit a base condition and stop recursing.

Comment: @FredYankowski model = { character : Dict String String ... }. getResponse k m = Dict.get k m.character. getResponseInt is same but applies toInt, returning the given default value if the hash key is missing or toInt fails. The recursion end condition is value reaching the count value from the hash. The first case increases it, the second case should tend towards the first case applying.

Comment: "I want to bubble the remainder up so that the old "ls-3" will become "ls-2" and so on." Could it help to store the dict keys in an Array. The Array is then used to capture the intended key order. Slice items off the Array, then remove from the Dict any key not in the Array. http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Array.